# Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_web_secure_offloaderheader

Tags: magento, zend-framework, error-handling, module, admin

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and recently I have installed patches. It seems all the patches have been installed.

But I am facing a strange issue. Under system->configuration->web I am getting a below error

```
Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_web_secure_offloaderheader
```

I have found on Google that it is suggested that there could be a file missing at this location:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Secure/Offloaderheader.php
```

which is right and I have created a file there, but still I am facing the same issue.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possibilities:

- Path of file which you have mentioned above should be:
  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Secure/Offloaderheader.php

instead of
    app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/web/secure/Offloaderheader.php

- Your code in Offloaderheader.php is not same as below:

  class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Web_Secure_Offloaderheader extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
  {

  protected $_eventPrefix = 'core_config_backend_web_secure_offloaderheader';

  }

Please let me know if issue still persists.

Comment: sorry to say but the patch is correct , i write wrong in lowercase here but it is correct on server , the issue is still there.I have also edited my question.  thanks